# SmallDateTime In SQL Server

Tags: smalldatetime

How can I retrieve only the TIME in the **SmallDateTime** datatype in SQL using SELECT Command?

Comment: You only want to select time from datetime column? Can you paste your query in there.

Comment: SELECT
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108) AS HourMinuteSecond,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),101) AS DateOnly
GO The first query return time and the second one return only date.

Answer (score 0):

This will give the hour:

```
Select datename(hh, date_variable) from table_name
```

This will give the minute:

```
Select datename(mi, date_variable) from table_name
```